# Mac App store Submission and In-App Purchase

Tags: ios, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm new to mac app submission to store. I have read a lot of guidelines from apple developer forums and websites. I have created the certificate and provisional for Mac app store submission, but its seems like “3rd Party Mac Developer Application”. For submission to store which one should be used?

Also about the In-App purchase, Is possible to use our own online payment mode in mac app? Please suggest me.
Thanks In Advance.

Comment: If you're distributing the software on the App Stores, you must use Apple's in-app purchase system or it'll get rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding In-App Purchase, you cannot use your own payment system. Source: https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies